# Check if an array of strings has all elements to create a given word

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Say you have an array of words

```
String[] arr = {"i", "a", "am", "good", "program", "gram"};
```

And a given key

```
String key = "iamgood";

boolean allWordsFound(arr, key){

// should return true if all possible words from array make up the key.
// e.g. keys matched {"i", "am", "good"};

}
```

My approach :

```
boolean workbreak(String[] arr, String key) {

StringBuilder tempStr = new StringBuilder();
String[] possibleValues;
int count = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < key.length()- 1; i++){
     tempStr.append(key[i]);
     for(j =0; j < arr.length(); j++){
         tempStr == arr[j]{
             return true;
             //possibleValues[count] = tempStr;
             //count++;
         }
     }
 }

}
```

I am unable to figure out an approach. I do not need code but can you please suggest an algorithm.

Comment: did you try anything to solve it by yourself?

Comment: @bart.s Yes I did, My approach was to run a loop on key and create all possible sub strings. Then check if those sub strings are present in the array. But the problem is I am unable to decide how to use the appropriate key. Eg : how to discard "a" and instead use "am"

Comment: paste your code in the problem description, so that we could revise your solution, and write exactly what are your doubts there. If we can't see your input, and there is no detailed description, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @bart.s updated the description. I am not looking for code. But more of an approach. Thank you

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to generate all possible permutations from the String array (arr) and check if the list of permutations contains a given word. When I find some other idea, I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Sort the String array by length, from longest to shortest:

```
{"i", "a", "am", "good", "program", "gram"};
```

becomes:

```
{"program","gram","good","am","a","i"}
```

The idea here is to match the longer words first, since in a case like this, you would want to match 'am' first before matching with 'a' (using the contains function).

Thus, the algorithm would check "program", then "gram", then "good" (matches), then "am" (matches), then "a", then "i" (matches).

The other solution is like bart.s stated in the comments: find all permutations, then check if any certain one matches. That will be a very slow algorithm though.